# undefined method `authenticate' for #<Login:0x007f04dd0df988>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have created a login page and i am entering a saved username and password on it. so when i am entering the id password its authenticating it and then redirecting me to a different page.but i am getting this error message iam not getting what should i do now i am new to ruby .sorry in advance if its a silly question but please help me out

** this is my controller

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def log
  end
  def attempt_login
    if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
      found_user = Login.where(:username => params[:username]).first
      if found_user
        authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      end
    end
    if authorized_user
      # mark user as logged in

      session[:username] = authorized_user.username
      flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in."
      redirect_to(:controller => 'Posts',:action => 'index')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination."
      redirect_to(:action => 'log')
    end
  end
  def logout
  end
end
```

** this is my view

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'attempt_login') do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:username) %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag(:username) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= label_tag(:password) %></td>
      <td><%= password_field_tag(:password) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><%= submit_tag("Log In") %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
```

** this is my model

```
class Login < ActiveRecord::Base 
end
```

** this is my db migrate file

```
class CreateLogins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :logins do |f|
      f.string  :username
      f.string :password
      f.string :role
    end
  end
   def down
    drop_table :logins
  end
end
```

Comment: `found_user.authenticate(params[:password])` line is expecting a `authenticate` method in the `Login` model. If you are totally new to ruby, best you follow a tutorial (eg: https://www.railstutorial.org/book) step by step so you get familiar with the concepts.

Comment: yes i am totally new thanks